# How do i pass values from view model to controller without use of list?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Continuing from my previous question, i pass the id value from 'Lookup' controller to another controller method 'Charges'.

```
Function Charges(id As String) As ActionResult
        Dim Patient As New LookupVM()

        Patient.GetHistory(paid)

        Return View(Patient)
End Function
```

In the view model, i have the GetHistory(id) list method, and listProcedure is the list holding the values that i want to pass back to the controller to be displayed in the view.

```
Public Property listProcedure As List(Of LookupVM)

Public Function GetHistory(id As String) As List(Of LookupVM)
    Using db As New DbContext()

        ' SQL query
        '====================
        Dim idd = New SqlParameter("@id", "%" & id & "%")
        Dim query As String = "select p.id id, pv.pvid pvid
                                    from patient p 
                                    join patient_visit pv on p.id = pv.id
                                    where p.paid like @id"
        Dim Results = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of LookupVM)(query, idd).ToList()

        For Each item In Results
            Dim pvid = New SqlParameter("@pvid", "%" & item.pvid & "%")
            Dim query2 As String = "select po.remarks remarks, po.entereddt entereddt, po.Consultant Consultant
                                    from procedure_order po 
                                    join procedures p on po.pdid = p.pdid
                                    where po.pvid like @pvid
                                    order by po.entereddt desc"
                Dim Results2 = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of LookupVM)(query2, pvid).ToList()

                For Each item2 In Results2
                    Dim ProcedureList2 As New LookupVM()
                    ProcedureList2.remarks = item2.remarks
                    ProcedureList2.entereddt = item2.entereddt
                    ProcedureList2.ForConsultant = item2.ForConsultant
                    listProcedure.Add(ProcedureList2)
                Next

        Next

        Return listProcedure
    End Using

End Function
```

I'm wondering if i'm able to pass those values to the controller through something else other than a list. if possible, what could it be? Because if its a list, i can't display them on the page without the use of foreach loop.

Another question is, is my code conceptually correct or wrong? Because when i run, it took me 5 minutes to display a list of 72 values which involves the code above. I think it took way too long. Is there any way to make it load faster?

Answer (score 0):

About the List, there is nothing wrong with doing `For Each` in a View. If it is needed then it is needed, and no reason to avoid it.

Some query tips (it is hard to do better for lack of details):

- If your `paid` and `pvid` columns are `INT`, then do not query them using `LIKE @id` but using `= @id` (without `%` in it). Even if they are `(N)VARCHAR` then using LIKE would need to be justified and explicit. If done by accident then output will often be wrong.
- `LIKE '%value%'` causes indexes to be ignored, possibly leading to bad performance.
- Make sure that you have indexes on the columns that you use to JOIN on.
- Try combining the two queries into one, to limit the number of .NET/DB roundtrips.

Comment: I had to use LIKE, because they are not int values. its varchar because its something like 'A123'. Sorry, i don't quite understand: "have indexes on the columns that you use to JOIN on." How do i know if i have indexes? Are they the same as primary key?

Comment: I'm not criticizing the use of list. I still use list for displaying values in a table. its just that i need to display the values in separate places in the view. For your easy understanding, i take an example of the placement of my values from this page. What i'm trying to achieve is something like the 'asked viewed active' part at the top right of this page. The value 'today', '20 times' and 'today' is retrieved from the database. i had to do the foreach loop for each part enclosing the 'asked viewed etc'. If not, when i run the page with no values yet, that whole part will not display

Comment: About using LIKE, remember that if A12 can occur then `LIKE %A12%` will match both `A12` and `A123`. About indexes: in Management Studio, expand [+] the table, then expand [+] Indexes. Use right-click menu item "New Index" if needed.